# Keep table synced with another but with accumulated / grouped data

Tags: postgresql, triggers

If I have large amounts of data in a table defined like

> CREATE TABLE sensor_values (   ts TIMESTAMPTZ(35, 6)       NOT NULL,
> value          FLOAT8(17, 17) DEFAULT 'NaN' :: REAL  NOT NULL,
> sensor_id      INT4(10)                              NOT NULL, );

Data comes in every minute for thousands of points. Quite often though I need to extract and work with daily values over years (On a web frontend). To aid this I would like a sensor_values_days table that only has the daily sums for each point and then I can use this for faster queries over longer timespans.

I don't want a trigger for every write to the db as I am afraid that would slow down the already bottle neck of writes to the db.

Is there a way to trigger only after so many rows have been inserted ?
Or perhaps an index and maintains a index of a sum of entries over days ? I don't think that is possible.

What would be the best way to do this. It would not have to be very up to date. Losing the last few hours or a day would not be an issue.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like a materialized view might work for you.

Comment: Materialised view does seem like a good fit but it sounds
like REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW would rebuild a table of all points and data. I think that would takes many hours unless it does an intelligent update since last run ? Still reading up on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the best way to do this.

Install clickhouse and use AggregatingMergeTree table type.

With postgres:

Create per-period aggregate table. You can have several with different granularity, like hours, days, and months.

Have a cron or scheduled task run at the end of each period plus a few minutes. First, select the latest timestamp in the per-period table, so you know at which period to start. Then, aggregate all rows in the main table for periods that came after the last available one. This process will also work if the per-period table is empty, or if it missed the last update then it will catch up.

In order to do only inserts and no updates, you have to run it at the end of each period, to make sure it got all the data. You can also store the first and last timestamp of the rows that were aggregated, so later if you check the table you see it did use all the data from the period.

After aggregation, the "hour" table should be 60x smaller than the "minute" table, that should help!

Then, repeat the same process for the "day" and "month" table.

If you want up-to-date stats, you can UNION ALL the results of the "per day" table (for example) to the results of the live table, but only pull the current day out of the live table, since all the previous days's worth of data have been summarized into the "per day" table. Hopefully, the current day's data will be cached in RAM.

It would not have to be very up to date. Losing the last few hours or a day would not be an issue.

Also if you want to partition your huge table, make sure you do it before its size becomes unmanageable...

Comment: Thanks. Interesting ideas here. PS the table is partitioned into year quarters already but I didn't want to complicate the original question.

Comment: Nice. I was mentioning it because of the guy who asked a question the other day trying to delete old records from a 3TB table that he didn't partition, so he couldn't drop partitions, and the index updates from the delete nuked his IO performance

Answer (score 1):

Materialized Views and a Cron every 5 minutes can help you:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Incremental_View_Maintenance

In PG14, we will have INCREMENTAL MATERIALIZED VIEW, but for the moment is in devel.